# Нужна ли запятая между двумя глаголами в одинаковой форме, стоящими рядом?

Tags: пунктуация

Нужна ли запятая? Каким правилом регулируются такие случаи?

Сидим (,) пьем чай. Сижу (,) жду.

Comment: Посмотрите обсуждение здесь: https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/14472/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d1%8f%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d0%b4%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%b3%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b0-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d1%8f%d1%82-%d1%80%d1%8f%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%b2-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%84%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d0%b5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В обоих случаях запятая факультативна. 
Я бы убрал её в первом и оставил во втором.
***Сидим пьем чай. Сижу, жду***

Два глагола подряд можно трактовать либо как два однородных сказуемых, либо как одно осложненное.

Вот примеры не разделяемых запятой конструкций.

> НЕ разделяются запятой:
>
> 1) Глаголы в одинаковой форме, указывающие на движение и его цель.
>   Пойду погуляю.
>   Сядь отдохни.
>   Пойди посмотри.
>   2) Образующие смысловое единство.
>   Ждет не дождется.
>   Посидим поговорим.

http://baddcat.livejournal.com/92274.html

Так вот, в первом случае такое понимание (движение и цель и/или смысловое единство) вполне возможно, а во втором мало подходит по смыслу, сидеть и ждать - два одинаково актуализованных глагола.

Пока писал, нашли более подробный ответ на ресурсе. Там всё исчерпывающе:

> В случае, когда два глагола стоят в одинаковой форме, причем один
>   указывает способ, а второй цель действия, имеет место осложненное
>   глагольное сказуемое.
>
> Запятые в этом случае не ставятся.
>
> dic.academic.ru

http://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/14472

@Серж

> Запятая в подобных примерах не ставится, т. к. здесь нет однородных
>   членов предложения.

Совершенно некорректное утверждение. Кто вам сказал, что их нет? Вы же цитируете источник, где явно прописаны необходимые условия для такого. И это только необходимые, не достаточные.  В одном случае - уж точно  запятая возможна, если не необходима. "Сижу, жду" - вполне себе однородные члены.

(++)

Продолжаем разговор.

Серж (допускаю, что не только он), возможно, не понимает формулировки правила.

Да, у Розенталя, а потом и у Лопатина использована "школьная" формулировка, "глагол движения + его цель". Это работает в сочетаниях типа "пойду покурю". Но совершенно не очевино для "сижу, курю" и подобных. "Сидеть" - не глагол движения, да и "курю" - очень сомнительная цель "сидения". И, таким образом, совершенно не очевидно, что это не однородные члены.

Есть более общая формулировка. **"Один указывает способ, а второй цель действия"** (см. цитату выше). В таком варианте "Сижу" вполне может считаться способом действия, и "курю" (с некоторой оговоркой) тянет на цель его.

Но даже в этом случае это только допустимая, совершенно не однозначная трактовка. С полным основанием можно считать это и двумя однородными членами, выражающими одинаково актуальные действия. То есть запятая (или её отсутствие) тут зависит от авторского понимания - и таким образом раскрыть оттенки смысла.

По поводу смыслового единства ("единого смыслового целое"). Что это такое, неизвестно. У Розенталя не спросишь, а Серж не отвечает. Я считаю, что рассматриваемые пары не тянут на подобное, каждый глагол сам по себе описывает действие и это разные, независимые действия. В таких случаях это предоставляется решать автору. Открыл тему, получил один ответ - [Смысловое единство пары глаголов](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/432420)

Всё это очень здорово, но вряд ли Розенталь с Лопатиным могли пользоваться подобным определением. По большому счету, я вообще сомневаюсь, что "сериализация" и смысловое единство - одно и то же. Короче, прояснения не наступило.

Comment: @slava1947 да, уже поправили, спасибо. Если интересно, это мое редактирование неудачное. Я там свои случаи рассматривал, в другом порядке. А потом увидел ссылку на старый вопрос, все убрал, но не заметил этого момента.

Answer (score 3):

**СТАТИСТИКА НАЦКОРПУСА** http://search2.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&req=%F1%E8%E4%E8%EC+%EF%FC%E5%EC

Сидим, пьем (чай, кофе и т.д.): 27 примеров, из них 24 примера с запятой и 3 примера без запятой.
**Может быть,  эта статистика поможет вам выбрать ответ.**

**Правило:**

Розенталь [XXII. ЗНАКИ ПРЕПИНАНИЯ В ПРЕДЛОЖЕНИЯХ С ОДНОРОДНЫМИ ЧЛЕНАМИ](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/43.htm)

**Не ставится запятая.**
а) между двумя глаголами в одинаковой форме, указывающими на движение и его цель или образующими **единое смысловое целое** (в таких сочетаниях нет однородных членов), например: Я забегу возьму рукавицы (Гоголь); Зайду проведаю (Л Толстой); ср. сочетания: сядь посиди, попробуй узнай, посидели поговорили, жду не дождусь и т.п.;

**Решение:**  **Сидим, пьем чай** (второй глагол имеет дополнение).

Два варианта: **Сижу жду. Сижу, жду** (перечислительная интонация)

**Примеры из Нацкорпуса:** Сидим, ждем начала.  Делать нечего, сидим ждем. Сидим, ждём: час, второй, третий.

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ 1**

**Вопрос о смысловом единстве во многих темах решается факультативно,** то есть является авторским решением, связан с интонацией, со структурой конкретного предложения.

1) **Когда ставится запятая**

(1) Влияние дополнения на постановку запятой (дополнение относится ко второму глаголу, поэтому нет смыслового единства).

(2)Когда однородный ряд продолжается (перечислительная интонация)

После первого дня выступления на Олимпиаде **сидим, ждем итогов.** [Наталья Бестемьянова и др. Пара, в которой трое (2000-2001)] ― Не торопись, ― осадил его Федор, ― лучше пушку готовь.

Сидим, ждем хороших барышей и не чуем беды. [И. А. Бунин. Хорошая жизнь (1911)]

**Сидим, ждем,** не дергаемся до поры. Как я их увижу, замочим и делаем ноги. [Алексей Грачев. Ярый-3. Ордер на смерть (2000)]

Мы обычно на ней сидим, ждем тебя. [Г. Я. Бакланов. Мой генерал // «Знамя», 1999]

И мы сидим, ждем, тоже совещаемся.  [Андрей Некрасов. Приключения капитана Врунгеля (1960-1980)]

2) **А вот при отсутствии дополнения возможны варианты (авторское решение)**, причем чаще встречаются варанты с запятой

Ночь и впрямь, как в песне, вышла темная-претемная. Сидим, ждем, меня нетерпенье жжет. «Не спит все», ― думаю. [С. А. Есенин. Яр (1915)]

Отпустили мы его в полдни. Сидим, ждем. [В. М. Дорошевич. Сахалин (Каторга) (1903)]

Запихали в ящик, убрали мел с доски, сидим ждем. [Дмитрий Каралис. Автопортрет (1999)]

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ 2.**

Хочу напомнить темы, в которых **наличие зависимого слово "нарушает тесное единство".**

1) При наличии зависимого слова **термин переходит в свободное словосочетание**: Розенталь: При наличии пояснительных слов обычно образуется свободное словосочетание (наречие и прилагательное или причастие), а не терминологическое сложное слово. Ср.:  малоисследованные проблемы — мало исследованные **наукой** области медицины.

2) При двух однородных членах с повторяющимся союзом и запятая не ставится, если образуется **тесное смысловое единство** (обычно такие однородные члены **не имеют при себе пояснительных слов**), например: Были и лето и осень дождливы...

При наличии у однородных членов **пояснительных слов запятая в этих случаях обычно ставится,** например: Срубленные осины придавили собой и траву, и **мелкий** кустарник (Тургенев); Все вокруг переменилось: и природа, и характер **леса** (Л. Толстой).

Comment: @ Sibylla,на мой взгляд, в примере "сидим пьем чай" одно действие. Хотя, действительно, в интернете встречаются примеры с запятой.

Comment: Серж,  при наличии дополнения есть пауза, фраза не говорится на одном дыхании. Дополнение относится ко второму глаголу, ну какое тут смысловое единство?

Comment: – Sibylla, при запятой смысл меняется, появляются два действия, а не одно.

Comment: Серж,  всё же условно, правила дают возможность в каждом конкретном случае  выбрать удобную форму, в том числе для произношения. Сюда и третье действие можно прибавить: сидим, пьем чай, разговариваем.

Comment: Sibylla, вот и я говорю о том: запятая говорит о различных действиях, т. е. свидетельствует о последовательности.

Answer (score 1):

Запятая в подобных примерах не ставится, т. к. здесь нет однородных членов предложения.

Не ставится запятая.

а)       между двумя глаголами в одинаковой форме, указывающими на движение и его цель или образующими единое смысловое целое (в таких сочетаниях нет однородных членов), например: Я забегу возьму рукавицы (Гоголь); Зайду проведаю (Л Толстой); ср. сочетания: ***сядь посиди, попробуй узнай, посидели поговорили, жду не дождусь и т.п.***;

См.: Д. Э. Розенталь. Справочник по правописанию и стилистике.

**Дополнение**

> **«Московские новости»** составили список конструкций, в которых чаще всего появляются лишние знаки препинания.

3. «Пойдем(,) поедим», «сижу(,) читаю»
   В таких сочетаниях часто ставят запятые, потому что ошибочно принимают их за однородные члены предложения. Но это не так.

**«Сижу читаю»** — это одно действие, а не два разных. Просто тут есть основное действие, а есть «поддействие».

Так же, как и в случае «пойдем поедим». Пойдем — приглашение, направление, поедим — цель. Вместе они образуют одно действие.

Comment: *Запятая в подобных примерах не ставится, т. к. здесь нет однородных членов предложения.* - совершенно некорректное утверждение. Кто вам сказал, что их нет? Вы же сами цитируете источник, где явно прописаны необходимые условия для такого. И это только необходимые, не достаточные.  В одном случае - уж точно  запятая возможна, если не необходима. "Сижу, жду" - вполне себе однородные члены.

Comment: Вы видите ошибки там, где их нет. Зато свои не замечаете. Вы даже уже считаете себя выше Розенталя. Смешно ведь! Прошу вас, больше не отвечайте! А если вы не согласны с моим ответом, дайте свой ответ, а меня не трогайте в своих ответах!

Comment: Серж, вы можете обсудить правила ресурса на Мете. А требование не замечать ваших ошибок противоречит не только правилам, но и самой сути ресурса.  Комментарий нужно оставить, если вы хотите:

    попросить автора уточнить вопрос;
    представить конструктивную критику, которая поможет автору улучшить сообщение;
    сделать уместное дополнение, содержащее не самую распространенную информацию, или, возможно, описание временного явления (например, ссылку на соответствующий вопрос или предупреждение автору о том, что вопрос был обновлен).  (С) Справка

Comment: Ищите свои ошибки! Их  у вас уйма!  А про ответы, которые основаны на субъективном мнении и противоречат здравому смыслу, я уже молчу.

Comment: По поводу ответов!\Кричать в ответах,кому можно доверять, а кому - нет, не вам решать! Научитесь элементарной культуре.

Comment: Ни одно из ваших замечаний не было конструктивным! Беда в том, что вы считаете ваши ответы самыми правильными. Из всех ваших ответах только видно одно: "Никому не доверяйте на форуме, только мне!".

Comment: Серж *Кричать в ответах,кому можно доверять, а кому - нет, не вам решать!* - вы не могли бы на русском писать? )))  *Ищите свои ошибки! Их у вас уйма* - если так, почему вы ни разу мне на них не указали? ))) Вон slava1947 указал прямо в этой теме. Я только поблагодарил. И никакого крика.