# Смысловое единство пары глаголов

Tags: терминология

Вопрос вырос из другого.
Вот цитата из Розенталя.

> Не ставится запятая... между двумя глаголами в одинаковой форме,
>   указывающими на движение и его цель или ***образующими единое смысловое***
>   ***целое*** (в таких сочетаниях нет однородных членов), например: Я забегу
>   возьму рукавицы (Гоголь); Зайду проведаю (Л Толстой); ср. сочетания:
>   ***сядь посиди, попробуй узнай, посидели поговорили, жду не дождусь*** и
>   т.п.;

(Курсив мой)

Как вы понимаете, что такое "единое смысловое цело" пары глаголов?
Я столкнулся с тем, что внятного определения нет, а интуитивно понимают по-разному.

Розенталевские примеры заставляют предположить, что "единое смысловое целое" означает здесь ситуацию, когда оба глагола говорят об одном и том, дополняют друг друга, причем значение их сочетания прямо не вытекает из составляющих, но  усиливается ими.
Это так?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    что такое "единое смысловое целое" пары глаголов?
```

Вообще, единое смысловое целое - слитное сочетание, т.е. два или несколько слов обозначают вместе что-то одно, при этом  их нельзя разделить, они являются одним членом предложения.

Этот термин (по отношению к паре глаголов) употребляется для анализа глагольного сказуемого. Составное глагольное - слитное сочетание вспомогательного глагола и инфинитива(умею петь), простое глагольное  может выражаться словом и сочетанием слов, которое является смысловым целым.

Неоднословное простое глагольное сказуемое - или фразеологически неделимое глагольно-именное сочетание (пойти прахом=разрушаться), или повтор глагола, глагол с частицей (Удружил так удружил,  знай себе держись!), или  инфинитив с личной формой того же глагола, которой предшествует частица не, для усиления отрицательного значения сказуемого ( Сам работать не работает, да и другим мешает), или сочетание двух однокоренных глаголов и частицы не между ними, с модальным значением невозможности (Ждем не дождемся весны),или сочетание оборота "только и делаю, что"  с последующим глаголом в той же форме для обозначения интенсивности действия (Он только и делает, что рисует),  или то самое **смысловое единство пары глаголов,** т.е. **смысловой глагол с вспомогательной глагольной формой, утратившей или ослабившей своё лексическое значение и вносящей в предложение дополнительные смысловые оттенки**:

*А он возьми да и скажи / знай себе распевает.* Оба глагола в одинаковой форме, но глагол "возьми" с ослабленным значением,( никто ничего не берёт), он вносит оттенок произвольности в  действие "сказать".

Это, в отличие от фразеологического единства, фразеологически свободное, но синтаксически связанное словосочетание.

Иногда к нему же относят сочетание  глагола "пойти" с другим глаголом, обозначающим цель. Это тоже смысловое единство, но вспомогательный глагол здесь не вносит оттенок, а указывает цель движения: зайду проведаю, пойду погуляю, пойди почитай. Розенталь его выделяет отдельно, но его не следует путать с сочетанием сказуемого "пойти" и инфинитива-обстоятельства : пойду (куда? зачем?) гулять, пойду петь.

Comment: Людмила, а нельзя как-нибудь попроще? Человек, читающий Розенталя, не обязан во всем этом разбираться. И если вводится некое понятие без определения, оно должно быть самоочевидным. Вопрос-то имеет чисто практический аспект. Тут у нас один товарищ на голубом глазу уверяет, что "сижу(,) жду" - и есть то самое "единое смысловое целое". И ссылается при этом на Розенталя.

Comment: Я-то с ответом в целом согласен. (*В отношении "пойди почитай" - с оговоркой, это не "единое смысловое целое, Розенталь его выделяет в отдельную группу "способ действия + цель действия", но это частности*.) Вопрос, как это все объяснить обычному читателю Розенталя?

Comment: По-моему, сижу, жду - два равноправных глагола, два действия, происходящих одновременно, между ними можно поставить союз И, Можно этот ряд продолжить: сижу, жду, смотрю по сторонам и лузгаю семечки. Это однородные сказуемые. В этой паре глаголов нет полноправного, основного действия и ослабленного, вносящего какой-то  оттенок в действие "жду". Можно сказать: жду, сидя на скамейке, но сидя - не оттенок, а полноправное добавочное действие - деепричастие.

Comment: @Людмилa, если это два равноправных глагола, тогда и "сижу читаю" можно рассматривать  как два равноправных глагола. А вот «Московские новости» считают иначе. Там есть статья (автор к.ф.н. Ксения Туркова) пишет: 3. «Пойдем(,) поедим», «сижу(,) читаю»
В таких сочетаниях часто ставят запятые, потому что ошибочно принимают их за однородные члены предложения. Но это не так. ***«Сижу читаю»*** — это одно действие, а не два разных. Просто тут есть основное действие, а есть «поддействие».

Comment: Так же, как и в случае «пойдем поедим». Пойдем — приглашение, направление, поедим — цель. Вместе они образуют одно действие.

Comment: Пойдём поедим - согласна, а вот сижу читаю - спорно. По-моему, зависит от контекста и интонации.Вот у Довлатова:" А у этого что на уме? .. Короче, сижу, читаю газету. А молодые люди продолжают нарушать"[Сергей Довлатов. Марш одиноких (1982)]


Или Толстой:" И она показала в лицах и в разных голосах: ― Я сижу, читаю, конечно." [А. Н. Толстой. Хождение по мукам/ Книга третья. Хмурое утро (1941)] Явно однородные сказуемые. Ну, а если так:" Сижу читаю, никого не трогаю" - то возможно и без запятых, здесь и правда одно действие, если вдуматься.

Answer (score 2):

В рамках терминологии, именующей такие сочетания глаголов *сериальными глагольными конструкциями*, формулируют признаки глаголов, входящих в сериальную конструкцию (я немного упростил формулировки):

> - а) глаголы описывают одно событие,
> - б) имеют как минимум один общий актант [участник действия],
> - в) имеют одинаковые грамматические характеристики,
> - г) один из глаголов не подчиняется другому,
> - д) интонационные характеристики - такие же, как при одном глаголе,
> - е) только одно подлежащее,
> - ж) тенденция образовывать устойчивое сочетание.
>
> (Рассказы о сновидениях: Корпусное исследование устного русского
>   дискурса, под ред. Кибрика и Подлесской, "Языки славянских культур",
>   Москва 2009)
>
> https://books.google.ru/books/content?id=WavJAAAAQBAJ&hl=ru&pg=PA249&img=1&zoom=3&ots=LHUSExI_K_&sig=ACfU3U11RhcDR981kT3VcOHqeckS4Q8FwQ&w=1280
>
> https://books.google.ru/books/content?id=WavJAAAAQBAJ&hl=ru&pg=PA250&img=1&zoom=3&ots=LHUSExI_K_&sig=ACfU3U3v3kq2taOqdpkHQ56AoyTqiTApSA&w=1280

Из этого можно заключить, что "смысловое единство" опирается на *связи с другими членами предложения*, в то время как способность глаголов образовывать устойчивое сочетание типична, но не обязательна.

Comment: Вы не о том. Вы описываете условия **применения** правила, а я спрашиваю про сам термин. Но вообще - спасибо. За ссылку. Интересно в полном виде это можно почитать?!