# Запятая между глаголами в предложении

Tags: пунктуация

*И в итоге ты сидишь психуешь.*

Нужна ли тут запятая?

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, здесь запятая не нужна, так как есть смысловое единство двух глаголов. Этот вопрос подробно обсуждался на нашем форуме. См., например, [Смысловое единство пары глаголов](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/432420/%d0%a1%d0%bc%d1%8b%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%8b-%d0%b3%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2) и   [Нужна ли запятая между двумя глаголами в одинаковой форме, стоящими рядом?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/432403/%d0%9d%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%8f%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%b6%d0%b4%d1%83-%d0%b4%d0%b2%d1%83%d0%bc%d1%8f-%d0%b3%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%84%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d0%b5-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d1%8f%d1%89%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d1%80%d1%8f%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%bc)