# Выйдем поговорим. Нужна ли запятая?

Tags: сказуемые

Может, выйдем, поговорим? (Петрушевская. Сырая нога, или Встреча друзей.)

А ну выйдем поговорим! Фуфло! (Чивилихин. Про Клаву Иванову.)

Возможно и с запятой, и без запятой?

Comment: Здесь [похожий вопрос](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/432403/%d0%9d%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%8f%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%b6%d0%b4%d1%83-%d0%b4%d0%b2%d1%83%d0%bc%d1%8f-%d0%b3%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%84%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d0%b5-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d1%8f%d1%89%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d1%80%d1%8f%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%bc/432406#432406).

Comment: Да, серьезный был разговор, и правило в редакции  Розенталя можно прочитать.

Answer (score 5):

Запятая не ставится в выражении: **Может,  пойдем поговорИм?** Здесь нет интонации перечисления, две формы глагола однородными не считаются.

**Может, вЫйдем, поговорим?** Здесь возможны колебания, так как ударение падает на глагол с приставкой ВЫ, поэтому произнести две формы без паузы сложно. Да и семантика в этом случае более сложная (выйдем и поговорим).

**Пояснение**

**Вопрос № 251428**

Добрый день, меня интересует, по каким правилам оформляется пунктуация **в сочетаниях двух глаголов в личной форме.**

Например, "пойду поем", "пошли перекусили". Понятно, что они относят к разговорной речи, но все же место в языке они имеют. Интуиция и интонация говорят, что запятая не нужна, однако, с другой стороны это два глагола в одинаковой форме и без союза, т.е. нужна запятая. Как же быть? (если дадите ссылку на правило, будет великолепно)

Ответ справочной службы русского языка

**Запятая не нужна: пойду поем; пошли перекусили.** Правило таково: не ставится запятая между двумя глаголами в одинаковой форме, **указывающими на движение и его цель или образующими единое смысловое целое** (в таких сочетаниях нет однородных членов).

Comment: Если посмотреть на труды современных корректоров (через гугл-книги), то Чивилихинский вариант "белеет одиноким парусом". Преобладает вариант с запятой (даже в подзаголовках встречается), часто встречается тире (уточнение), местами - точка (добавление вдогонку).

Comment: Я думаю, что для этого есть причины (интонационные и смысловые). Глаголы считаются однородными.

Answer (score 0):

Это перечисляемые *однородные члены предложения*, и запятая *нужна* - в отличие от случая конструкции с инфинитивом, в которой возможна прямая смысловая связь между глаголами ("нужно не забыть выйти поговорить" или "давай выйдем поговорить").

Answer (score 0):

> Может, выйдем, поговорим? А ну выйдем поговорим!

Именно так! Во-первых, запятая здесь соответствует паузе. Во-вторых, слово *может* сочетается с перечислением, а слова "а ну" — никак.